# Knockout - foreach databind in 2 column table layout

Tags: html, knockout.js, html-table

I have the following table where I'm attempting to loop through coverage lines. I would like 2 columns with a different line in each, however my code duplicates the same coverage in each column. Any suggesions on how to get a 2 column layout without the repetition? Which element should my foreach binding go on? Thanks.

```
        <table class="coverage-table" data-bind="foreach: $root.clientVM.CustomCoverageLines">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Checked" />
                    <label>
                        <span data-bind="text: $data.Description"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Checked" />
                    <label>
                        <span data-bind="text: $data.Description"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle of the this failing? I'm not sure that I get what you're trying to achieve based on your code snippet alone. Are you trying to make it so that two observable arrays with differing numbers of elements are displayed side by side in two columns in a table?

Comment: No, just one observable array. Trying to display a different coverage from my array in each <td> element. Currently both <td>s in the same row display the same $data.Description, due to being within the same instance of the foreach binding. I'll work on a fiddle. Say I have 4 coverages: Medical, Dental, Vision and Life. Table should have 1 row with Medical and Dental, and a second row with Vision and Life. Currently it would display 4 rows, one with 2 medical columns, one with 2 dental columns, one with 2 vision columns and one with 2 life columns

Answer (score 4):

You could add a `computed` property to your model that structures the data in the way that you want. See this JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6gvtz51g/. An advantage to this approach is that you can specify a different row size if you would like.

### HTML

```
<table data-bind="foreach: coverageLineRows">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;

    self.coverageLines = ko.observableArray([
        'Medical',
        'Dental',
        'Vision',
        'Life'
    ]);
    self.coverageLineRowSize = ko.observable(2);
    self.coverageLineRows = ko.computed(function () {
        var rows = [];
        var i = 0;
        var lines = self.coverageLines();
        var size = self.coverageLineRowSize();

        while (i < lines.length) {
            rows.push(lines.slice(i, i += size));
        }

        return rows;
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about this as a solution? Its not as flexible as the solution given by @JackieChiles in that it would need some tweaking to work with different amounts of rows. But the code I've provided does provide for a prettier look for two columns and it also has the ability to keep track of the check boxes next to each of your items. I suspect a combination of both our solutions will be in your end product :)

```
    var vm = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.array = ko.observableArray([{
        name: ko.observable('Medical'),
        checked: ko.observable()
    }, {
        name: ko.observable('Dental'),
        checked: ko.observable()
    }, {
        name: ko.observable('Vision'),
        checked: ko.observable()
    }, {
        name: ko.observable('Life'),
        checked: ko.observable()
    }, {
        name: ko.observable('Other'),
        checked: ko.observable()
    }]);

    this.coverageSplit = ko.computed(function () {
        var retArray = [];
        var i = 0;
        var arrayUnWrapped = this.array();
        while (i < arrayUnWrapped.length) {
            if (i >= arrayUnWrapped.length - 1) {
                retArray.push({
                    col1: arrayUnWrapped[i],
                    col2: {
                        name: '',
                        checked: false,
                        hideThisCheck: true
                    }
                })
                console.log(retArray[retArray.length - 1]);
                break;
            }

            retArray.push({
                col1: arrayUnWrapped[i],
                col2: arrayUnWrapped[i + 1]
            });
            i += 2;
        }

        return retArray;
    });
    this.check_click = ko.observable('None');

    this.setLastClicked = function (name) {
       if (name.length > 0) self.check_click(name);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/sva9tnje/